# Insert paragraph / line break in field - Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to insert line break into a table cell (field), see the "w:br /". How can I actually do this?

I've got a tag in the document that contains a table, with a single table cell. Instead of copying the cell I want to insert text with line break inside the cell.

```
var row = new XElement("Row");
string annetBeskrivelse = string.Empty;
foreach (var field in table.Elements("Field"))
{
  foreach (SPListItem item in listItemCollection)
  {

    try
    {
        var listColumnName = field.Attribute("Name").Value;
        SPField listField = list.Fields[listColumnName];
        annetBeskrivelse += listField.GetFieldValueAsText(item[listColumnName]);
        annetBeskrivelse += "<w:br />";
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        LblErroMessage.Text =
            string.Format(
                "Invalid template document - refers to list column ({0}) that doesn't exist",
                field.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }
  }
  row.Add(new XElement("Field", field.Attribute("Name"),
    new XAttribute("Value", annetBeskrivelse)));
  table.Add(row);
}
```

I've tried:

```
"<w:br />"
"\n"
new Paragraph();
```

Comment: Did you try `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: If we're talking about Word Open XML then it's not quite that simple. The underlying Word Open XML for a table cell looks like this (without any of the formatting info): `<w:tc><w:r><w:t>Abc</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:r><w:t>def</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>` for a new paragraph or for a new line: `<w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>Abc</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:br/><w:t>def</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>` As you can see, a new RUN is required in both cases. In the first case, within the w:p and in the second case to hold the w:br/

Comment: Is the open xml sdk an option for you?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck if that fixes the problem yes.. could you manage a example?

Comment: @CindyMeister if I try to insert <w.br /> into the code it only showing it as "string" not as an line break

Comment: @diiN_ Environment.NewLine didnt work.. strange that it didnt actually nothing.

Comment: I'm not telling you to insert it literally. You don't tell us what tool you're using and you don't provide code that shows how all the objects you're using are defined. But the tool appears to abstract the WordOpenXML rather than writing the literal XML. If you don't tell us which tool this is no one can give you the exact syntax. We can only tell you what to look for so that you can research it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with tables in word myself, so to make it easier on myself I wrote a wrapper for table called `CustomTable`. In my `CustomTableCell` I made the following property to get/set content (including multiline cells):

```
public class CustomTableCell
{
   public TableCell Cell {get; private set;} //The open xml sdk TableCell class

   public string InnerText
   {
        get { return Cell.InnerText; }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return;
            Paragraph p = Cell.GetFirstChild<Paragraph>();

            if (p.ChildElements.Count > 1)
            {
                Run run = (Run)p.GetFirstChild<Run>().CloneNode(true);
                p.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
                run.RemoveAllChildren<Text>();
                run.GetMultiLineRun(value);
                p.AppendChild(run);
            }
            else
            {
                Run run = p.GetFirstChild<Run>();

                if (run != null)
                    run.GetMultiLineRun(value);
                else
                {
                    run = new Run();
                    p.Append(run.GetMultiLineRun(value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `GetMultiLineRun` method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Run GetMultiLineRun(this Run run, string s)
    {
        string[] lines = 
           s.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (lines.Length > 0)
        {
            //Don't add break after last line!
            foreach (string line in lines.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse())
            {
                run.AppendChild(new Text(line));
                run.AppendChild(new Break());
            }
            run.AppendChild(new Text(lines.Last()));
        }
        return run;
    }
}
```

Basically if there's only one run in a paragraph, I change the contents of it and if there's more than one run in a paragraph, I copy the first one, edit contents and delete the others. I only needed to totally replace contents in a cell though, so if you want to just edit existing content you'll need to adapt it a bit.

Writing a wrapper for stuff like this is really convenient, because working with tables in word directly is a nightmare and impossible to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
string[] lines = Value.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Run run = new Run(new Text(lines[0]));
if (lines.Length > 1)
{
  run.AppendChild(new Break());
  run.AppendChild(new Text(lines[1]));
}
paragraph.Append(run);
```

I had a similar issue. I ended up keeping the string, variable Value in the example, coming into the cell with "\n" as the line break. I split the string into an array on the line break. I only had a possibility of one break in my code but you could use a foreach to loop through if you have multiple line breaks.